# ggplot: Adding line outline to scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have thousands of datapoints across 10 minute time stamps over several days.
Drawing a scatterplot creates a repeating pattern, which I would like to emphasize.
[image]
In the image above, I would like to have a line drawn, outlining the shape of this scatter. More specifically, a line going through the maximum value of `value` for each `hour` tick.
I've tried adding the likes of `freqpoly` and `hist` but those do not fit this plot type (where `x` is the timestamps). I've also tried calculating the maximum per timestamp, but I can't use this in the same pot because the original data is in tall format (with multiple entries for every time stamp).

Example data:

```r
set.seed(999)
df <- data.frame('hour' = rep(seq(ISOdatetime(2019,12,1,0,0,0), by = '10 mins', length.out = 6), 3),
                 'value' = rnorm(18),
                 'category' = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 6))

ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = category), cex = 7) +
  theme_minimal()
```

And this is what I'd like the final product to look like (**black line added by hand**):
[image]

Comment: subset data for max value per hour first and use it in `geom_line`

Comment: @PoGibas I tried that, but then the maximums vector would have as many entries as there are hours, but not as many as there are observations which causes `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (38215): x, y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by moving the aesthetics for the `geom_point` into the actual argument. Then you can add a `stat_summary` to add the line as follows:

```
set.seed(999)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame('hour' = rep(seq(ISOdatetime(2019,12,1,0,0,0), by = '10 mins', length.out = 6), 3),
                 'value' = rnorm(18),
                 'category' = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 6))

# Valid for ggplot2 version 3.2.1.9000
# fun.y might be needed if running an earlier version
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = hour, y = value, color = category), cex = 7) +
  theme_minimal()+
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = max, aes(hour, value))

# Or you can simplify a little and just keep the color aesthetic in the geom_point
# Same result achieved

ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = value),) +
  geom_point( aes(color = category), cex = 7) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = max)+
  theme_minimal()
```

This allows you to add the lines and then add the summary statistics as a new "line" geometry.

[image: points with line through max]

Comment: The correct argument for this is `fun.y = `, just found that out after some trial and error. Thank you all the same, this is perfect!

Comment: @RonnyEfronny be careful with `fun.y` as it is deprecated, meaning that eventually it will go away (though I agree it is much more intuitive than generic `fun`). Glad to help

Comment: I mean that using `fun` throws and error (is not recognizable) nor does it appear in the documentation for `stat_summary()`.

Comment: Ahh good call, yes I'm on `ggplot2 3.2.1.9000` so that might be it

Comment: @RonnyEfronny updated solution to include the note about `fun` vs `fun.y`